# how to insert value into list of matplotlib since an other file?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, matplotlib

i have this script in py :

```
show_grid = True

with plt.style.context(('seaborn-darkgrid')):
    plt.plot([?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?], [?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?]) # the lists
    plt.ylabel('Temperatures °C')
    plt.xlabel('Dates')
    plt.title('Relevé des températures du mois de FEVRIER 2020')
    plt.grid(show_grid)
    plt.show()
```

and i would like to add values from an other file such as txt or json :

```
{'dicolist': ['22/02/2020', '+22.5']}
```

How should i proceed plz, and which format is better ?

```
dicolist=dict_keys(['02/02/2020']):dict_values(['+23.0'])
```

or

```
[
{key,value}
{key,value}
{key,value}
{key,value}
]
```

Help me !!??? :D

Comment: It is not really clear to me if you want to add the values of the `lists` to the `dictionary`, or add the values of the `dictionary` to the `lists`. Is it relevant that will you plot them?

Comment: Sorry about that, That's for adding the values of the dictionary to the lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have not really clear if you have already your dictionary or you have to decide the format of it. If I understood you correctly you can make like the following example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

dicolist = {'22/02/2020': '+22.5', '23/02/2020': '+18'}
list_a = ['19/02/2020','20/02/2020','21/02/2020'] # your lists
list_b = ['+20.5','+21.5', '+19'] # your lists

for key, value in dicolist.items():
    list_a.append(key)
    list_b.append(value)

list_a = [datetime.strptime(d, '%d/%m/%Y') for d in list_a]
list_b = [float(d) for d in list_b]

show_grid = True
with plt.style.context(('seaborn-darkgrid')):
    plt.plot(list_a,list_b) # the lists
    plt.ylabel('Temperatures °C')
    plt.xlabel('Dates')
    plt.title('Relevé des températures du mois de FEVRIER 2020')
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)
    plt.grid(show_grid)
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you re-define the 2 lists as empty? Anyway i think you need: dicolist = dict(zip(list1, list2)) – Joe 3 hours ago                                         Thank you Joe for your help. I was too diving intonext problem for thanking you, sorry about that.

Comment: No worries, hope the answer helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I've got some troubles with dicolist, because i don't know how to iterate into it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import json
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


f = open("data_temp.json")
list2 = json.load(f)
f.close

for letter in list2:
    print("List2: " + letter)

f = open("data_jour.json")
list1 = json.load(f)
f.close

for letter in list1:
    print("list1: " + letter)
"""
c, d = 1, 0
while d < 4:
    list2[c:c] = [list1[d]]
    c, d = c+2, d+1

print(list2)
"""
dicolist = {}

dicolist[list1[0]] = list2[0] # How can i iterate here with loop ?
dicolist[list1[1]] = list2[1]
dicolist[list1[2]] = list2[2]
dicolist[list1[3]] = list2[3]

print(dicolist)

list1 = []
list2 = []

for key, value in dicolist.items():
    list1.append(key)
    list2.append(value)

show_grid = True
with plt.style.context(('seaborn-darkgrid')):
    plt.plot(list1,list2) # the lists
    plt.ylabel('Temperatures °C')
    plt.xlabel('Dates')
    plt.title('Relevé des températures du mois de FEVRIER 2020')
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)
    plt.grid(show_grid)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: If it is part of your question, dont post it as an answer, but improve the question. Also, what kind of troubles? Please make them clear, so it Is possibile to answer in an effective way. I see you use part of the answer i posted. Did my answer solve your initial problem? If yes, mark as accepted and post a new question with your new doubts. :)

Comment: Why do you re-define the 2 lists as empty? Anyway i think you need: `dicolist = dict(zip(list1, list2))`

Comment: Understood ;) I need to catch values from `dicolist`. The 2 lists before were for catching values from json files. But thanks for your solution. I keep it ! `dicolist = dict(zip(list1, list2))`